# Como puedo hacer en el siguiente codigo para el caso de la division no me salga error al ingresar num2=0

Tags: python, poo, class

Como puedo hacer en el siguiente código para el caso de la división no me salga error al ingresar num2=0????

para la división quisiera saber como hacer para que no me salga error al dividir por cero.??

Este es el código en python. con orientación a objetos:

```
class calculadora:

    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.num1= float(num1)
        self.num2= float(num2)

    def sumar(self):
        suma = self.num1+self.num2
        print("La suma es: ", suma)
    
    def multiplicar(self):
        multiplicacion = self.num1*self.num2
        print("La multiplicación es: ", multiplicacion)

    def restar(self):
        resta = self.num1-self.num2
        print("La resta es: ", resta)

    def dividir(self):
        division = self.num1/self.num2
        print("La división es: ", division)

num1 = input("Ingrese Num1: ")
num2 = input("Ingrese Num2: ")
calculadora = calculadora(num1,num2)
calculadora.sumar()
calculadora.multiplicar()
calculadora.restar()
calculadora.dividir()
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría es que si el num2 = 0 entonces un mensaje que diga que no se puede dividir entre 0. Ya que la división entre 0 no está definida.

Comment: Valida que el divisor no sea 0 ??

Comment: puedes validar con un IF si el valor es cero, si es así que muestre un mensaje y en caso contrario que haga la división.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más simple es preguntar que `self.num2` sea distinto de ceros antes de realizar la división:

```
def dividir(self):
    if self.num2 != 0:
        division = self.num1/self.num2
        print("La división es: ", division)
    else:
        print("No se puede dividir por cero")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe! me estaba frikeando en esto!!